# Pulling changes from other's shared repository

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have a repository called "abc" and my team member has forked this repository as "fork_abc". He commited some changes to "fork_abc". Now I have a cloned repository called "clone_abc" in my local system.

How can I pull the changes from "fork_abc" to "clone_abc" . I want to verify the changes and then push it to "abc" later.

I tried using $ hg pull "fork_abc" ,

but it seems its not the correct way. I am using mercurial for this and not git.Can some suggest what is correct command for this operation.

Comment: I'm not sure -- is 'fork_abc' repository name or branch name? `hg pull path/to/repository` should work.

Comment: `hg pull <repo>` is the way, but you need the proper path. It would certainly help if you stated the error message, and the full paths to the repos.

Answer (score 0):

You could always `export` as patches the changes in `fork_abc`, review them as patches and then `import` them to `abc`.